How to calculate the surface tension limit theoretically?
When an object is submerging in a fluid with strong surface tension (e.g. a plastic cup sinking in a lake), it's very easy to see the surface tension in action. However, at some point, the surface reaches maximum deformation and simply ruptures, as seen in this video.
Theoretically, I'm aware that surface tension $\gamma$ is defined as $dE = \gamma dA$, and that there is some geometric implications regarding the angle at the contact point between the fluid's and the object's surfaces. Nevertheless, none of these seem to point towards a theoretical calculation of the maximum deformation point.
I have asked a fluid dynamics professor at a renowned Engineering institution and he said it is usually determined experimentally. Furthermore, I have found this vaguely related exercise 31 from this problem set that has a solution here. Neither of these answers really satisfy me.
Does anyone know how to theoretically estimate the maximum deformation that a fluid surface can withstand?

There is a way to get a theoretically-based handle on problems like this, as follows.
There is a field of physics and engineering that deals with what are called nondimensional groups or similitude parameters. These parameters allow you to get handy order-of-magnitude answers to questions that have to do with the relative magnitudes of competing physical effects, like for instance whether inertial forces or viscous forces are dominant in a particular incompressible fluid flow problem.
These parameters have names like the Reynolds number, Mach number, Weber number, Froude number, Nusselt number and so on. They allow you to construct correct scale models of things like ship's hulls, aircraft fuselages, heat exchangers, inkjet printhead nozzles, open flow channels, flexible skyscrapers and the like and then predict the behavior of the full-sized items in the real world.
I'll bet you one (1) sugar-glazed doughnut (my standard bet) that there is a similitude parameter that will work for the case of surface tension versus buoyant forces which will furnish the physical insight you seek.
Google nondimensional group or similitude parameter and let us know what you find so it can be shared with the rest of the community here.
Good luck! -NN
